Possible new series for $\pi$
In a recent (unfortunately over-hyped) preprint by Saha and Sinha, Field theory expansions of string theory amplitudes (arXiv:2401.05733), they present the following series for $\pi$:
$$\pi = 4 + \sum_{n=1}^\infty {1\over n!} \biggl({1\over n+\lambda} - {4\over 2n+1}\biggr)\biggl({(2n+1)^2 \over 4(n+\lambda)} - n \biggr)_{n-1},$$
where $\lambda$ is an arbitrary complex number and the Pochhammer symbol $(x)_n := x(x+1)\cdots(x+n-1)$.
Setting aside the unfortunate press coverage, as well as the question of the significance of this formula for $\pi$, what I'm wondering is whether it is new. The authors are physicists, and searching the literature for this type of thing is not always easy, so I figured that MathOverflow would be a natural place to ask.
A related, and perhaps easier, question is whether there are other known series for $\pi$ that involve a complex parameter $\lambda$ in the summand, but where the sum of the series is independent of the value of the parameter.

EDIT: Aninda Sinha asked essentially the same question on math.SE on March 8, 2024. See also the Numberphile interview of Sinha and Saha.

You might also want to keep an eye on https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4937730/is-the-new-series-for-a-big-or-even-medium-deal (which at least as of yet has no answers) ; I didn't ask it there but I'm also curious as to whether this formula is fundamentally new; I'll be keeping an eye on this too.

Not quite an arbitrary complex number: it needs to avoid the poles at negative integers. Also worth noting (as they do in the paper) that the $\lambda \to \infty$ limit gives the Leibniz formula, which may be useful in literature searches.

For a series that contains Pochhammer symbol of rational function of $n$ see Theorem 7.1 in this article https://link.springer.com/article/10.1023/A:1009809424076

@PeterTaylor I think one needs $\Re(\lambda)>-1$ for the series to converge.

https://youtu.be/t1ZnptSEPI8?si=upACg5uF97FQQ5Gc

@ModsAndStaffAreNotFair That "Mind Your Decisions" video is a pretty accurate layman's summary of the formula, but it doesn't help answer the question.

@Timothy_Chow, with $-s_1=\nu$ and $-s_2=1-\nu$ and $\nu\in\mathbb{Q}$ an infinite bi-parametric series for $\pi$ with the algebraic factor $\sin(\nu\pi)$ is got.  $\nu=1/6$ gives another rational series. Since this is a sui generis Beta function expansion, a lemniscate constant series with $s_1=s_2=-1/4$  is got, as well as expressions for other trascendental constants like $\Gamma(1/3)$ with $s_1=s_2=-1/3$. The paper also brings a 2nd Beta function expansion with a different rational argument for Pochhamers. One can apply the same approach as above to get other infinite families of series

As it has a free parameter $λ$ Ι have tried to prove it by the WZ method. However it seems that the function $G(n, λ)$ inside the summation is not hypergeometric in its two symbols $n$ and $\lambda$; that is, $G(n+1,\lambda)/G(n,\lambda)$ and $G(n,\lambda+1)/G(n,\lambda)$ are not rational functions.
I have not seen this formula for $\pi$ before in the literature despite that I know many other formulas. Although the series is not good for computing $\pi$ (contrary to what is stated in the press), it could have some interest. In the paper there is also a formula of the same style for $\zeta(2)$.Taking the limit of it as $λ \to \infty$ we obtained a well-known alternating series with a better convergence.

I am provisionally accepting this answer because it is probably the best answer we can hope for. Of course if someone eventually finds a very similar identity in the literature then I may have to change my mind.

My understanding was that as $\lambda\to\infty$ you get the Madhava series $\sum(-1)^n\frac4{2n+1}$, which converges quite slowly (more slowly than the Saha–Sinha series does for small values of $\lambda$). Is that wrong?

Jolley, Summation of Series, contains many "series that involve a parameter $\lambda$ in the summand, but where the sum of the series is independent of the value of the parameter." Here are just a few (the sum isn't generally $\pi$):
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{n-1}{(2n-2)!\over n!(n-1)!}{x^n(x+\lambda)^n\over\lambda^{2n-1}}=x\tag{412}
$$
$$
\sum_{k=1}^{\lambda}\cos{(2k-1)\pi\over2\lambda+1}={1\over2}\tag{424}
$$
$$
\sum_{k=1}^{(n-1)/2}{1\over\sin^2k\lambda}={n^2-1\over6}{\rm\ where\ }n{\rm\ is\ odd}\tag{439}
$$
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{(-1)^{n-1}\over2n-1}\cos(2n-1)\lambda={\pi\over4} 
{\rm\ where\ }-{\pi\over2}<\lambda<{\pi\over2}\tag{506}
$$
$$
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{\sin(n+{1\over2})\lambda\over n+{1\over2}}={\pi\over2}{\rm\ where\ }0<\lambda<\pi\tag{550}
$$

Yes Gerry, those are other nice examples of series involving a free parameter $λ$ that cannot be proved by the WZ method because the function $G(n, λ$ inside the summand is not hypergeometric in it's two symbols $n$ and $λ$.

Such examples are ample as coming from Fourier series expansion.

This is just a note that the case $\lambda=1/2$ is nothing more than the arcsine representation of $\pi$.
In this case, the identity becomes $$\pi=4+\sum_{n\ge1}\frac1{n!}\left(-\frac2{2n+1}\right)\left(\frac12\right)_{n-1}$$ or equivalently, \begin{align}\pi&=4-2\sum_{n\ge0}\frac1{4^n(n+1)(2n+3)}\binom{2n}n\\&=4-2\left(\sum_{n\ge0}\frac1{4^n(n+1)}\binom{2n}n-2\sum_{n\ge0}\frac1{4^n(2n+3)}\binom{2n}n\right).\end{align} Using $(1-x)^{-1/2}=\sum_{n\ge0}(x/4)^n\binom{2n}n$, we have \begin{align}\sum_{n\ge0}\frac1{4^n(n+1)}\binom{2n}n&=\int_0^1\frac1{\sqrt{1-x}}\,dx=2\\\sum_{n\ge0}\frac1{4^n(2n+3)}\binom{2n}n&=\int_0^1\frac{x^2}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}\,dx=\frac\pi4\end{align} so the identity is true.

Did you find any other (even as some bizarre hypergeometric functions) ?

$$\frac{2x \sqrt{1-x^2} +8 \sin
^{-1}\left(\frac{\sqrt{1-\sqrt{1-x^2
}}}{\sqrt{2}}\right)-2 \sin
^{-1}(x)}{x}$$

@ClaudeLeibovici, the value $\lambda=\frac14$ also looks interesting because it allows some simplification: we get $$\frac{\pi}{4} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{- 1}{2n(2n+1)} \binom{\frac{4n^2}{4n+1}}{n}$$

@PeterTaylor. Thanks. What is interesting is thé diagonal part makes "most" of thé job. Cheers

@PeterTaylor Taking $\lambda=0$ gives $$1-\frac\pi4=\sum_{n\ge1}(-1)^n\frac{2n-1}{2n+1}\binom{-\frac1{4n}}n.$$ I have come across binomials like $\binom{\frac1k}n$ but not when both terms depend on $n$.

I think you've missed the offset when converting from the Pochhammer symbol (which is a notation I avoid because IMO it's easier to misread than to read correctly) to the binomial: I think it should be $$\frac{\pi}{4} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1 - 2n}{(2n+1)(1 + 4n^2)} \binom{\frac{4n^2 + 1}{4n}}{n}$$

@PeterTaylor Both expressions are correct, I manipulated it further (binomial identities/gamma reflection formula etc) so that the binomial coefficient no longer involves a quadratic.

@TheSimpliFire I'm surprised you've offered a bounty for this question. If the answer is that the identity is new, how much evidence would you need before you would award the bounty?

It would be nice proving the formula without using concepts coming from Physics. Perhaps @TheSimpliFire is offering a bounty for such a proof.

@JesúsGuillera If the desire is for a proof, then TheSimpliFire should post a completely separate MO question, asking for a proof. The present question asks whether the identity is new. It will be confusing to all concerned if these two distinct questions are mixed together in the same MO question.

@TimothyChow You are right..

Thanks @TimothyChow and JesusGuillera, I have posted my question separately: https://mathoverflow.net/q/474141/113397

This is NOT an answer. This type of series involving Pochammer symbols $(a)_n$ with $a$ a rational function of $n$ is totally new to me. Reading the paper,
I summarize below what I extracted (and simplified) from it:
(1) For $p\in{\mathbb Z}_{\ge-1}$ we have
$$\dfrac{\Gamma(s_1)\Gamma(s_2)}{\Gamma(s_1+s_2-p)}=(-1)^p\sum_{n\ge0}\dfrac{1}{n!}\left(\dfrac{1}{n+s_1}+\dfrac{1}{n+s_2}-\dfrac{1}{n+\lambda}\right)\left(1-\lambda+\dfrac{(\lambda-\
s_1)(\lambda-s_2)}{n+\lambda}\right)_{n+p}\;.$$
The formula for $\pi$ follows by choosing $s_1=s_2=1/2$ and $p=-1$, but in my opinion the formula with $p=0$ is slightly more elegant.
(2) $$\psi(1+x)+\gamma=x\sum_{n\ge1}\dfrac{1}{n!}\left(\dfrac{2n+x}{n^2+nx}-\dfrac{\
1}{n+\lambda}\right)\left(1-\dfrac{\lambda(x+n)}{n+\lambda}\right)_{n-1}\;.$$
Choosing $x=-1/2$ gives a formula for $\log(2)$ similar (but simpler) to that
for $\pi$.
(3) $$\zeta(2)=-\sum_{n\ge1}\dfrac{(n+2\lambda)}{\lambda n^2n!}\left(-\dfrac{n\lambda}{n+\lambda}\right)_n\;.$$
as well as similar but more complicated formulas for $\zeta(j)$ for $j\ge3$.

This is an answer to the related post
Proof of "Possible new series for $\pi$" without use of physics
but it seems relevant also for this question. My guess is that this formula is new as it stands, but it follows easily from classical results.
I found an elementary proof using partial fractions. This is motivated by Nemo's observation that very similar-looking series appear in the work of Schlosser (Section 7). The matrix inversion used by Schlosser is closely related to partial fractions, see e.g. https://www.arxiv.org/abs/math/0309358.
Fix $\lambda$ and let $t_1$ and $t_2$ be variables satisfying
$$t_1+t_2-\frac{t_1t_2}{\lambda}=1-\frac{1}{4\lambda}. $$
By elementary facts about partial fraction expansions, we can write
\begin{equation}\label{pf}\frac{(t_1+t_2+1)_n}{(t_1)_{n+1}(t_2)_{n+1}}=\sum_{k=0}^n A_k\left(\frac{1}{t_1+k}+\frac 1{t_2+k}-\frac 1{\lambda+k}\right), \qquad (1)\end{equation}
where
$$A_k= \frac{(t_1+k)(t_1+t_2+1)_n}{(t_1)_{n+1}(t_2)_{n+1}}\Bigg|_{t_1=-k}.$$
The last term in (1) makes each term vanish in the limit
$t_1\rightarrow\infty$, $t_2\rightarrow \lambda$ (and vice versa).
Writing
$$a_k=t_1+t_2\Big|_{t_1=-k}=1-\frac{(2k+1)^2}{4(\lambda+k)}, $$
this can be simplified to
$$A_k=\frac{(a_k+1)_{k-1}(-1)^k}{k!(n-k)!(a_k+n+1)_{k}}. $$
Specializing $t_1=t_2=1/2$ in  (1) gives
$$\frac{(2)_n}{(1/2)_{n+1}^2}=\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{(a_k+1)_{k-1}(-1)^k}{k!(n-k)!(a_k+n+1)_{k}}\left(\frac{4}{2k+1}-\frac 1{\lambda+k}\right). $$
We now multiply both sides by $n!$ and let $n\rightarrow\infty$. The left-hand side can be written
$$\frac{\Gamma(n+2)\Gamma(n+1)}{\Gamma(n+3/2)^2}\cdot\frac{\Gamma(1/2)^2}{\Gamma(2)}\rightarrow \frac{\Gamma(1/2)^2}{\Gamma(2)}=\pi.$$
On the right, we have the factor
$$\frac{n!}{(n-k)!(a_k+n+1)_{k}}=(-1)^{k}\frac{(-n)_{k}}{(a_k+n+1)_{k}}\rightarrow 1. $$
This gives (it should not be hard to justify taking the limit)
\begin{align*}\pi&=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^k}{k!}\left(\frac{4}{2k+1}-\frac 1{\lambda+k}\right)\left(2-\frac{(2k+1)^2}{4(\lambda+k)}\right)_{k-1}\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{1}{k!}\left(\frac 1{\lambda+k}-\frac{4}{2k+1}\right)\left(\frac{(2k+1)^2}{4(\lambda+k)}-k\right)_{k-1}
, \end{align*}
which is the desired identity.
More generally, one could start with variables satisfying
$$t_1+t_2-\frac{t_1t_2}{\lambda}=x+y-\frac{xy}{\lambda}, $$
take the partial fraction expansion of
$$\frac{(t_1+t_2-p)_n}{(t_1)_{n+1}(t_2)_{n+1}}, $$
specialize $t_1=x$, $t_2=y$
and finally let $n\rightarrow\infty$. I checked that this gives equation
(4) in the paper by Sana and Sinha (where $x=\alpha-s_1$, $y=\alpha-s_2$). Presumably other identities in their paper follow by further variations of the same argument.

@JorgeZuniga: I just solve the first equation for $t_2$. It gives
$$t_2=\frac{4\lambda-4t_1\lambda-1}{4(\lambda-t_1)}.$$
I then plug in $t_1=-k$ and $t_2=(4\lambda+4k\lambda-1)/4(\lambda+k)$ in $t_1+t_2$ and simplify.

@Hjalmar_Rosengren. Ok, Thanks a lot.

This is a non-answer-followup to the non-answer of @HenriCohen:
Noting that
$$\tag{*}\label{eq:*}
1-\lambda+\frac{(\lambda-s_1)(\lambda-s_2)}{n+\lambda}=
\frac{(n+s_1) (n+s_2)}{n+\lambda} -n-s_1-s_2+1$$
and (note the big confusion regarding the notation of factorial powers) using the (falling) factorial power $a^{(n)}=a(a-1)\cdots(a-n+1)$ instead of the Pochhammer symbol aka. rising factorial power $(a)_{n}=a(a+1)\cdots(a+n-1)$, Henri's first equation simplifies to
\begin{align}
\frac{\Gamma(s_1)\Gamma(s_2)}{\Gamma(s_1+s_2-p)}
=(-1)^p \sum_{n\ge 0}\frac{1}{n!}&\left(\frac{1}{n+s_1}+\frac{1}{n+s_2}-\frac{1}{n+\lambda}\right) \times{}\\
\tag{1}\label{eq:1}
&{}\times\left(\frac{(n+s_1) (n+s_2)}{n+\lambda} -(1+s_1+s_2)\right)^{(n+p)}.
\end{align}
Note that
\begin{align}\tag{**}\label{eq:**}
\frac{\partial}{\partial n}\ln\frac{(n+s_1) (n+s_2)}{n+\lambda} = 
\frac{1}{n+s_1}+\frac{1}{n+s_2}-\frac{1}{n+\lambda}.
\end{align}
Similarly, Henri's second equation can be written as (I use $s_2$ instead of $x$ and add some zeroes)
\begin{align}
\frac{\psi(1+s_2)+\gamma}{s_2}= \frac{H_{s_2}}{s_2}=
\sum_{n\ge 1}\frac{1}{n!}&\left(\frac{1}{n+0}+\frac{1}{n+s_2}-\frac{1}{n+\lambda}\right)\times{}\\
\tag{2}\label{eq:2}
&{}\times\left(\frac{(n+0)(n+s_2)}{n+\lambda} -(1+0+s_2)\right)^{(n-1)},
\end{align}
with the harmonic numbers $H_n$ (analytically continued).
The two equations are related through a Laurent series expansion of \eqref{eq:1} at $p=-1$ around $s_1=0$ according to
\begin{align}\tag{3}\label{eq:3}
-\frac{\Gamma(s_1)\Gamma(s_2)}{\Gamma(s_1+s_2+1)} =
-\frac{1}{s_1 s_2}+\frac{H_{s_2}}{s_2} + \mathcal{O}(s_1),
\end{align}
where the divergent term $\frac{-1}{s_1 s_2}$ is equal to the $n=0$ term in \eqref{eq:1}. The constant term at $s_1=0$ in this expansion is the rhs of \eqref{eq:2}.
Finally, Henri's third equation is given by the limit $s_2\to0$ of \eqref{eq:2}.
Maybe, equation \eqref{eq:**} sheds some light onto the discussion.


A related, and perhaps easier, question is whether there are other known series for  that involve a complex parameter  in the summand, but where the sum of the series is independent of the value of the parameter.

I have something that more or less qualifies if we allow a slightly loose interpretation of the question. In my 2004 paper "Explicit formulas for hook walks on continual Young diagrams" I proved the following identity:
$$
\pi = \int_0^1 \left[
\cos\left(\frac{\pi g(x)}{2}\right) 
x^{-(1+g(x))/2}
(1-x)^{-(1-g(x))/2}
\exp\left(
\frac12 \int_0^1 \frac{g(u)-g(x)}{u-x} du
\right)
\right] dx.
$$
(See the second page of the Introduction.)
Here, the "parameter" is an arbitrary smooth function $g:[0,1]\to(-1,1)$, not a single complex number. And the expression is not a sum, it's an integral. But it is a formula for $\pi$, and it's valid independently of the value of the parameter.

this might be a stupid question (it is far from what I do). But if you take $g$ to be a step function and approximate it with smooth functions and then take the limit shouldn't you get a sum? Then couldn't you increase the number steps and get in the limit a series? Though, I am not sure this is interesting,

@YiftachBarnea a limit of sums is not always a sum. In this case it’ll be an integral. By the way, the integration identity is proved precisely by starting with a discrete summation identity and taking a limit more or less as you suggest.

Thanks, I guess the intuition was right, but its direction was wrong. :-)

In second thought, here is a slightly less stupid idea. Fix g, then integrate from 0 to 1/2, then from 1/2 to 3/4, then from 3/4 to 7/8, and so on. You get a series that depends on g. Again, no idea if it is interesting.

This answers the final question about other parametric similar series for $\pi$. Working on the Saha & Sinha paper, it is possible to get a bi-parametric generalization of a related formula. If $s\in\mathbb{Q}$ with $0<s<1$ and $\lambda\notin\mathbb{Z}_{\le0}$, then
$$ \pi=\sin\pi s\cdot\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{1}{n!}\cdot\left(\frac{1}{n+s}+\frac{1}{n+1-s}-\frac{1}{n+\lambda}\right)\cdot\left(1-\lambda+\frac{(\lambda-s)(\lambda-1+s)}{\lambda+n}\right)_n $$ which is a logarithmically behaved series that can be summed up using some efficient acceleration method. For instance, H. Cohen's $\Delta$-Euler-MacLaurin. Note that this is a rational expression just for $s=\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{6},\frac{5}{6}$. For other rational $s$ values $\sin\pi s$ gives an algebraic factor.
