Proof of "Possible new series for $\pi$" without use of physics
 Related post: The post Possible new series for $\pi$ is about whether the identity is new, so to avoid confusion I was advised to ask this question separately. 

I am looking for a proof of the following identity that does not require knowledge of physics:
$$\pi = 4 + \sum_{n\ge1}\frac1{n!}\left(\frac1{n+\lambda}-\frac4{2n+1}\right)\left(\frac{(2n+1)^2}{4(n+\lambda)}-n\right)_{n-1}\tag1\label{474141_1}$$ for any $\operatorname{Re}\lambda>-1$ where $(x)_n= x(x+1)\cdots(x+n-1)$ is the Pochhammer symbol.

The current proof relies on various quantum field theory concepts.  So far, only the case $\lambda=1/2$ is resolved, as the term inside the Pochhammer being independent of $n$ makes the calculations more straightforward.
It may help that \eqref{474141_1} can be rewritten in terms of fractional binomial coefficients: $$\pi=4-4\sum_{n\ge1}(-1)^n\left(\frac{2n}{4n^2-4\lambda+1}-\frac1{2n+1}\right)\binom{-\frac{4(1-\lambda)n+1}{4n+4\lambda}}n.\tag2\label{474141_2}$$

Just two brief comments:
I don't understand much of the original paper but it certainly does not seem to prove the identity.
Another known case is the limit $\lambda\rightarrow\infty$, which is the Madhava-Leibniz series.

Is anyone familiar enough with the methods of the paper to comment on whether there is even a proof sketch in there? I skimmed it and it really does not seem like there are enough details to indicate even vaguely what the ideas of the proofs are. It's like they're using some arcane version of the residue theorem or something.

By extending the Pochhammer symbol one step more and cancelling out, it's possible to subsume the leading $4$ as the $n=0$ term, which IMO is more elegant: $$\frac{\pi}{4} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1 - 4\lambda - 2n}{(2n+1)(1 - 4\lambda + 4n^2)} \binom{\frac{4n^2 - 4\lambda + 1}{4n+4\lambda}}{n}$$

@HjalmarRosengren  You think that the authors have not proved that the sum is independent of the parameter λ. Right?

@JesúsGuillera I don't want to say too much. Perhaps there is some reasoning behind what they do that could be converted to a mathematical proof. In that case it is well hidden.

I "protected" the question, to stop the AI generated non-answers.

That is a formel power series , what about Fourrier transforme ?or i may ask what about  its inversion formula  ?

https://youtu.be/t1ZnptSEPI8?si=upACg5uF97FQQ5Gc

I found an elementary proof using partial fractions. This is motivated by Nemo's observation that very similar-looking series appear in the work of Schlosser (Section 7). The matrix inversion used by Schlosser is closely related to partial fractions, see e.g. this paper.
Fix $\lambda$ and let $t_1$ and $t_2$ be variables satisfying
$$t_1+t_2-\frac{t_1t_2}{\lambda}=1-\frac{1}{4\lambda}. $$
By elementary facts about partial fraction expansions, we can write
$$
\label{pf}\frac{(t_1+t_2+1)_n}{(t_1)_{n+1}(t_2)_{n+1}}=\sum_{k=0}^n A_k\left(\frac{1}{t_1+k}+\frac 1{t_2+k}-\frac 1{\lambda+k}\right), \tag 1
$$
where
$$
A_k= \frac{(t_1+k)(t_1+t_2+1)_n}{(t_1)_{n+1}(t_2)_{n+1}}\Bigg|_{t_1=-k}.
$$
The last term in \eqref{pf} makes each term vanish in the limit
$t_1\rightarrow\infty$, $t_2\rightarrow \lambda$ (and vice versa).
Writing
$$
a_k=t_1+t_2\Big|_{t_1=-k}=1-\frac{(2k+1)^2}{4(\lambda+k)}, 
$$
this can be simplified to
$$
A_k=\frac{(a_k+1)_{k-1}(-1)^k}{k!(n-k)!(a_k+n+1)_{k}}. 
$$
Specializing $t_1=t_2=1/2$ in \eqref{pf} gives
$$\frac{(2)_n}{(1/2)_{n+1}^2}=\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{(a_k+1)_{k-1}(-1)^k}{k!(n-k)!(a_k+n+1)_{k}}\left(\frac{4}{2k+1}-\frac 1{\lambda+k}\right). $$
We now multiply both sides by $n!$ and let $n\rightarrow\infty$. The left-hand side can be written
$$\frac{\Gamma(n+2)\Gamma(n+1)}{\Gamma(n+3/2)^2}\cdot\frac{\Gamma(1/2)^2}{\Gamma(2)}\rightarrow \frac{\Gamma(1/2)^2}{\Gamma(2)}=\pi.$$
On the right, we have the factor
$$\frac{n!}{(n-k)!(a_k+n+1)_{k}}=(-1)^{k}\frac{(-n)_{k}}{(a_k+n+1)_{k}}\rightarrow 1. $$
This gives (it should not be hard to justify taking the limit)
\begin{align*}\pi&=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^k}{k!}\left(\frac{4}{2k+1}-\frac 1{\lambda+k}\right)\left(2-\frac{(2k+1)^2}{4(\lambda+k)}\right)_{k-1}\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{1}{k!}\left(\frac 1{\lambda+k}-\frac{4}{2k+1}\right)\left(\frac{(2k+1)^2}{4(\lambda+k)}-k\right)_{k-1}
, \end{align*}
which is the desired identity.
More generally, one could start with variables satisfying
$$t_1+t_2-\frac{t_1t_2}{\lambda}=x+y-\frac{xy}{\lambda}, $$
take the partial fraction expansion of
$$\frac{(t_1+t_2-p)_n}{(t_1)_{n+1}(t_2)_{n+1}}, $$
specialize $t_1=x$, $t_2=y$
and finally let $n\rightarrow\infty$. I checked that this gives equation
(4) in the paper by Sana and Sinha (where $x=\alpha-s_1$, $y=\alpha-s_2$). Presumably other identities in their paper follow by further variations of the same argument.

Humans 1 - AI 0

Maybe some people would prefer to write $t_1=t$ and substitute $t_2=(\lambda-t\lambda-1/4)/(\lambda-t)$ everywhere. Then we have completely standard partial fraction expansions in the variable $t$. I only introduce the variable $t_2$ to make the symmetries of the expressions more explicit.

@HjalmarRosengren It occurred to me that since the Sinha-Saha series can be thought of as a generalization of Madhava's series, perhaps there is a way to generalize Madhava's correction term as well? Any thoughts about that?

@TimothyChow Good question, I will think about it. I started writing a short paper about the Sinha-Saha-type series.

My paper on this topic is now available at
https://arxiv.org/abs/2409.06658
